# Possible SOAP version mismatch

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I have a problem with web service connection. It says,

> Possible SOAP version mismatch:
>   Envelope namespace
>   http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ was
>   unexpected. Expecting
>   http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.

when i call webservice's method. Do you have any idea about my problem?

Comment: I fixed this problem with [this solution](http://sanjaysainitech.blogspot.ae/2010/05/error-possible-soap-version-mismatch.html). Hope it helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're providing the wrong namespace when creating the SOAP envelope - it should look similar to this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

It's the third one that is probably wrong in your case.

Comment: In which file? `wsdl`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue dealing with a legacy web service hosted on a mainframe(obviously not .net). The url for the service was specified in the config of the client, but the wsdl file had not been included in the deployment.  I suspect that on the initial call, the .Net client attempted to retrieve a fresh wsdl.  The service wasn't expecting that and we received the "Possible SOAP version mismatch" error.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error, because we set the c#-WebServiceProxy-URL to a wrong value.

we did

```
WebService ws = new WebService();
ws.Url = "http://URL_TO_WEBSERVICE?WSDL";
var response = ws.CallFunction()
```

Here the ?WSDL at the end of the URL caused the error.